# How to show cursor for opengl application usingSDL?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Here is what I am doing to setup opengl and SDL context and the window

```
SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("program", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1366, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
glewInit();
SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);
SDL_Cursor * cursor;
cursor = SDL_CreateSystemCursor(SDL_SYSTEM_CURSOR_HAND);
SDL_SetCursor(cursor);
SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_ENABLE);
```

The mouse just doesnt show at all, even though I am still getting mouse event.

Comment: Do you know what `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);` does? Do you really need it? Removing it makes the cursor appear.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need it because I want cursor's offset to its last position

Comment: Then you don't need it. You'll get relative mouse events regardless. Enabling relative mode means you ONLY want relative events.

Comment: "While the mouse is in relative mode, the cursor is hidden, and the driver will try to report continuous motion in the current window" from https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode. If you need relative offset, just cache the previous position in your main loop and calculate the difference.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's an easy fix. Thank you very much sir, for your promptness. Please write an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: Why are you calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` *after* `SDL_CreateWindow()`?  Those those only affect the *next* `SDL_CreateWindow()` call.